# prettyPhoto max width and height on pop up too big

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prettyphoto

im using the latest version from [No Margin for Errors](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) and setting allow_resize to true but still it's waay to big.. how do i set the max width/height for it?

i've already set view port to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

img {max-width:100% !important;}

Place this line to stylesheet and check!